# GDAL DEMProcessing returning -9999 values

Tags: python, tiff, gdal

I'm working with some DEM data I've downloaded from the USGS and am trying to calculate the slope, aspect, and hillshade data of the TIFF file downloaded. Here is the code I'm using:

```
slope_cmd = "gdaldem slope clipped_by_coords.tif slope_clipped_1.tif"
os.system(slope_cmd)

slope = gdal.Open('slope_clipped_1.tif')
slopeArray = slope.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
```

But when I open the `slopeArray` array, it is filled with values of -9999. I know the clipped_by_coords.tif file is correct as I opened it in QGIS, so I'm not sure what is happening in between that is causing this issue. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!